# Reading a text file which is a matrix

Tags: python, matrix, cluster-computing

I have a text file which is in matrix format I want to read this file and want to create a dendrogram but I have an Error.

This is my text file's content:

> Kaynak: YSK
>
> Adalar
>
> Istanbul location Adalar.svg
>
> d • t
>
> Toplam secmen sayisi  Toplam sandik sayisi
>
> 12,369    45
>
> Adaylik   Sonuclar
>
> Kis.  Parti   Aday    Oy sayisi   Oy orani
>
> CHP   Cumhuriyet Halk Partisi Atilla Aytac    5.207   %50.1
>
> AK Parti  Adalet ve Kalkinma Partisi  Coskun Ozden    4.381   %42.1

```
import re
import feedparser
import clusters

def getwordcounts(url):

    print url
    d = feedparser.parse(url)
    wc = {}

    for e in d.entries:
        if 'summary' in e:
            summary = e.summary
        else:
            summary = e.description

        words = getwords(e.title + ' ' + summary)
        for word in words:
            wc.setdefault(word, 0)
            wc[word] += 1
    try:
        return d.feed.title, wc
    except AttributeError:
        return None,None
def getwords(html):

    txt = re.compile(r'<[^>]+>').sub('',html)

    words = re.compile(r'[^A-Z^a-z]+').split(txt)

    return [word.lower() for word in words if word != '']

apcount = {}
wordcounts = {}
feedlist = []

for feedurl in file('cc.txt'):
    title, wc = getwordcounts(feedurl)
    if title != None:
        feedlist.append(feedurl)
        wordcounts[title] = wc
        for word,count in wc.items():
            apcount.setdefault(word,0)
            apcount[word] += 1


wordlist = []
for w,bc in apcount.items():
    frac = float(bc) / len(feedlist)
    if frac > 1 and frac < 2:
        wordlist.append(w)

out = file('sa.txt','w')
out.write('Blog')
for word in wordlist:
    out.write('\t%s' % word)
out.write('\n')
for blog_title, wc in wordcounts.items():
    blog_title = blog_title.encode('ascii'
,'ignore')
    out.write(blog_title)
    for word in wordlist:
        if word in wc:
            out.write('\t%d' % wc[word])
        else:
            out.write('\t0')
    out.write('\n')


blognames, words, data = clusters.readfile('sa.txt')
clust = clusters.hcluster(data)
clusters.drawdendrogram (clust, blognames, jpeg = 'cl.jpg')

reload(clusters)
clusters.printclust(clust,labels = blognames)
```

And this is my cluster function;

```
def readfile(filename):
  lines=[line for line in file(filename)]

  # First line is the column titles
  colnames=lines[0].strip().split("\t")[1:]
  rownames=[]
  data=[]
  for line in lines[1:]:
    p=line.split('\t')
    # First column in each row is the rowname
    rownames.append(p[0])
    # The data for this row is the remainder of the row
    data.append([float(x) for x in p[1:]])
  return rownames,colnames,data
```

ERROR CODE :

> colnames=lines[0].strip().split("\t")[1:]
>   IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 1):

The error is because the first line does not have a tab character in it and the line is not being split at all. Or, if the first character is a tab, it is being removed with the .strip() command.

You can print the line while showing the special characters in order to check if the tab characters exist:

```
print repr(lines[0])
```

Comment: Thanks mate, but if the problem is it what should i do to fix it I am so new in pyhton.

Comment: It's hard to say anything more specific than "don't assume things which are not true". If you genuinely require each line to contain a tab, maybe edit the input file so it meets this requirement. If not, you will have to rearticulate your program's logic to say what you really mean.